# How to add a device to an existing Ad-Hoc Provisioning Profile?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

Have just noticed that Apple redesigned iOS Dev Center this weekend.

I need to add a couple of devices to an existing Ad-Hoc provisioning profile. But when I push Edit button, I can change only Name and App ID.

Is it any way to do it except of the obvious one: to delete the existing profile and create a new one with all required devices?

**UPD.**

Now I can edit the list of devices for development profiles, but not for distribution.

**UPD. 2**

Can edit devices for new distribution profiles, but can't do it for old.

Comment: Wow, they botched that up.  I can't find how to do it either. :(

Comment: @RichardBrown think that it's just a bug. hope they'll fix it.

Comment: Apple seems to have fixed the issue, I can now see the list of devices for the profiles.  We should close this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### It Works!

Apple fixed it. So it was a bug. Now you can edit your embedded device list, even if it's an Ad Hoc distribution profile.

Comment: are you sure about this? have just checked it - don't see the list of devices for distribution profiles (can see it for development profiles).

Comment: Yes. Just double checked now. It is there for both development and distribution profiles.

Comment: I see! have added one more distribution profile just to test it. and I see devices section for this profile. but I don't for old profiles.

Comment: maybe they are updating servers now.. and I still use non-updated. will check several hours later!

Answer (score 8):

I looked into this on the forum and found a reference to the new [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).  You need to delete your old profile and create a new one.  You'll be given the choice at that time to add devices to the new profile.  The feeling is that Apple has changed the format of the profile and this is a way of forcing you to recreate a new profile in the new format.

Comment: Do you mean that every time we want to add a new device e.g. to an Ad Hoc distribution profile, we have to create a brand new one?

Comment: If so, then what is the advantage of doing so? That is really not cool.

Comment: Even after you've deleted/re-created a new profile, you can't seem to ever modify the list of devices. You always have to delete an recreate. Hopefully they will improve this soon!

Comment: Check out this hack. Seems to be working - https://gist.github.com/ashtom/d0aeb62eedbfd555b04e

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can't edit it (generate button isn't enabled) if for example you have underscores in the profile name.

Comment: Yes exactly, underscores will not work for creating a new profile either

Comment: Please file bugs on this. It is very annoying since we like to name our profiles with names like com_company_product_adhoc.